# socket.io and cross-domain connections

Tags: cross-domain, xss, socket.io, same-origin-policy

As [their faq](http://socket.io/#faq) states, socket.io supports cross-domain connections on every browser.
Could someone tell me, if cross-domain-communications then uses a particular transport mechanism like long-polling, or does it work with all supported mechanisms.
Annother thing is `var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');`. This is used the client to connect to the socket.io server. As this establishes a connection by WebSockets, longpolling, etc.. the above connect method itself uses a regular http request. Would not at least this request violate the same origin policy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested it in `IE 8` and `FireFox 14`:

Cross-domain works for

- jsonp
- xhr-polling
- Websocket
- flashsocket

Cross-domain does not work for

- htmlfile

`htmlfile` btw in general only works in IE, whereas `websocket` does not work in IE (< 10). `flashsocket` does not work in browsers that support `websocket`, which is why I tested that one in IE8 only.